# C# Generic Constrains Issue

Tags: c#, .net

I am receiving following error .

> *The type 'Test.ICacheProvider' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'TStorageProvider' in the generic type or method
>   'StorageManager.Test.IFileInfo'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from
>   'StorageManager.Test.ICacheProvider' to
>   'StorageManager.Test.IStorageProvider'.*

Is anything wrong within this program design structure ?

**Program :**

```
// Cache Provider Classes

public interface ICacheProvider { }

public class BaseCacheProvider : ICacheProvider { }

public class DerivedCacheProvider : BaseCacheProvider { }

// Storage Classes
public interface IStorageProvider<TCacheProvider> where TCacheProvider : 
    ICacheProvider { }

public interface BaseStorageProvider<TCacheProvider> : 
    IStorageProvider<TCacheProvider> where TCacheProvider : ICacheProvider { }

public interface DerivedStorageProvider : BaseStorageProvider<ICacheProvider> { }

// User Classes
public interface IFileInfo<TStorageProvider> 
    where TStorageProvider : IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider> { }

public class FileInfo : IFileInfo<ICacheProvider> { }
```

Comment: Could you show us the line that produces the error?

Comment: There is error on line of declaration of FileInfo class.

Comment: Am I missing something missing in this program?

Comment: Well the error message says *The type '`Test.ICacheProvider`'*, but the code you provided does not define a class `Test`.

Comment: Immediately after the comment `// Storage Classes`, you define three **interfaces**. Which is wrong, the comment or the code?

Answer (score 7):

The error is in the definition of `FileInfo` class. You set the template parameter to `ICacheProvider` but the constraint is that the template argument must be `IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider>`.

This would probably be better:

```
public interface FileInfo
          : IFileInfo<IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider>>
```

Even your names do not match: `IFileInfo` needs **storage** provider but you give it **cache** provider.

Comment: Or change declaration of ICacheProvider to: `public interface ICacheProvider: IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider>`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Can `ICacheProvider` have a constraint, that requires itself to be a type argument of another interface?!

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can only constrain something that isn't known beforehand. You can "constrain" one interface to ensure that it inherits another though.

Comment: @Aschratt: Yes you can; try changing the code - it will compile! What it means is... more complicated. ;)

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but the precise wording is "a class or an interface can inherit a generic class or interface whose generic parameter can be the class or interface itself".

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Sorry... I had a typo... "constraint" was wrong, I meant *"inherit from an interface, that requires the inheriting interface as a generic parameter"*... If it works that's good to know! I wasn't aware of this! ^^ Sounds a little bit like "generic recoursion", which I only knew from C++ meta programming.

Comment: @Ashratt: It's a bit like (but not identical to) the "Curiously recurring template pattern": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints are missmatching:

```
// User Classes
public interface IFileInfo<TStorageProvider> 
    where TStorageProvider : IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider> { }

public class FileInfo : IFileInfo<ICacheProvider> { }
```

`FileInfo` is declared as an `IFileInfo` with an generic argument of type `ICacheProvider`. However `IFileInfo` has the constraint that let's it only accept `IStorageProvider`s. And `ICacheProvider` isn't an `IStorageProvider`.