# C# Generic Covariance

Tags: c#, .net

**I am getting error on DerivedFileInfo class declaration.**

> *Error : The type 'StorageManager.Test.DerivedStorageProvider' cannot
>   be used as type parameter 'TStorageProvider' in the generic type or
>   method 'StorageManager.Test.BaseFileInfo'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'StorageManager.Test.DerivedStorageProvider'
>   to 'StorageManager.Test.IStorageProvider'.*

**Is there is something missing for generic constrains or I will require generic covariant?**

```
public interface ICacheProvider
{
}

public class BaseCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
}

public class DerivedCacheProvider : BaseCacheProvider
{

}

public interface IStorageProvider<TCacheProvider> where TCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
}

public abstract class BaseStorageProvider<TCacheProvider> : IStorageProvider<TCacheProvider> where TCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
}

public class DerivedStorageProvider : BaseStorageProvider<DerivedCacheProvider>
{
}

public interface IResourceInfo<TStorageProvider> where TStorageProvider : IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider>
{
}

public abstract class ResourceInfo<TStorageProvider> : IResourceInfo<TStorageProvider>
    where TStorageProvider : IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider>
{
}

public abstract class BaseFileInfo<TStorageProvider> : ResourceInfo<TStorageProvider> where TStorageProvider : IStorageProvider<ICacheProvider>
{
}

public class DerivedFileInfo : BaseFileInfo<DerivedStorageProvider>
{ 
}
```

Comment: Is not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656014/c-sharp-generic-constrains-issue?

Comment: This program compiles if I use covariance for interface definition.

Comment: No. I have mistyped above program. So program is was not same as this.

Comment: Adding a covariant param to the `IStorageProvider` should work, `public interface IStorageProvider<out TCacheProvider> where TCacheProvider : ICacheProvider` and I can't see any issues with this - is there any reason you think that this might not be the right solution?

Comment: I haven't issue with that solution. But I am very new to C# generics. So I want to try more better solution than covariance if any available.

Comment: Since you are using a derived type as the generic parameter for `IStorageProvider` you can't do this without covariance. If you were to use any other type derived from `ICacheProvider` you would get the same error. A covariant generic seems the right thing to do - obviously I can't comment much more as I don't know enough about the implementation from looking at a set of interfaces